# Installation driver rtl8188ce

Tags: 13.10

With

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Should I add rtl8192ce or rtl8188ce?

In the https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver the author say to me: insert
`rtl8192ce.ko`

Which one is right?

Answer (score 0):

The package you linked builds several drivers including rtl8192ce. Which one you require depends on your specific device. I assume you know you need rtl8192ce, but, if you have any doubt, please give us some additional details about your device:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

The correct format in /etc/modules is simply the driver name without the .ko extension:

```
rtl8192ce
```

Answer (score 0):

`rtl8192ce` is the correct driver.  The RTL8188CE does not have its own, rather it shares with the 8192ce.

`udev` should detect your hardware and load the right module anyway, but this is just a fail-safe.